# Too many inputs specified for the "split" filter

Tags: ffmpeg, split

I just tried to stitch 2 files and tried to get multiple outputs parallely:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v:0] [0:a:0] [1:v:0] [1:a:0] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1, split=2[out1][out2]" -map '[out1]' -preset ultrafast -vn -b:a 128k -c:a aac  tes45.mp4 -map '[out2]' -preset ultrafast -vn -b:a 128k -c:a aac  tes46.mp4
```

But it didn't work:

```
Too many inputs specified for the "split" filter.
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument
```

Comment: You should always at least show the actual error: it's just as important as your command. Otherwise we can only guess what the problem is. Even better is if you show the complete log from the command.

Comment: Hello, in above case can i extract only audio? That's why I used vn to neglect video.  Actually my requirement is,  1. I have 4 input files. 2. need to stitch all 4 files into single segment. 3. need output with 4.(500k,800k,1000k,1500k)different video bit rate.5. along with that i need to extract only audio from stitched file. so my output will be 4 different video bitrate + 1 audio only file

Comment: You should have included that information in the original question. My answer addresses the specific issue in your current question. You should ask a new question, such as "How to concatenate and output various video bitrates and a standalone audio file?", instead of asking different, follow-up questions that require new answers.

Comment: Ok will open a new question

Answer (score 0):

(a)[split](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#split_002c-asplit) only takes one input, but you're trying to feed it multiple inputs, and you were only mapping the video, but then excluding it with `-vn`.

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v:0][0:a:0][1:v:0][1:a:0]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a];[v]split=2[v1][v2];[a]asplit=2[a1][a2]" -map "[v1]" -map "[a1]" -preset ultrafast -b:a 128k -c:a aac tes45.mp4 -map "[v2]" -map "[a2]" -preset ultrafast -b:a 128k -c:a aac tes46.mp4
```

Because it appears you are using the same encoding settings for both outputs using the [tee muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#tee) would be a better choice.